# WCF C# SOAP Request - int32 error

Tags: web-services, wcf, soapui

I try to do following request to a WCF Web Service located here:

http://service.dreamlogistics.se/?wsdl

Full SOAP Request (SOAPUI):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dre="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DreamLogisticsService" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<tem:AddDelivery>
     <tem:Credentials>
        <dre:PartnerId>XX</dre:PartnerId>
        <dre:Password>XX</dre:Password>
        <dre:UserName>XX</dre:UserName>
     </tem:Credentials>
     <tem:Delivery>
        <dre:CashOnDelivery>0</dre:CashOnDelivery>
        <dre:CashOnDeliveryUnit></dre:CashOnDeliveryUnit>
        <dre:Comment></dre:Comment>
        <dre:ContactPerson></dre:ContactPerson>
        <dre:DealId></dre:DealId>
        <dre:DeliveryAddress>
           <dre:Address1>Testgatan 10</dre:Address1>
           <dre:Address2></dre:Address2>
           <dre:City>Stockholm</dre:City>
           <dre:CountryCode>SE</dre:CountryCode>
           <dre:CustomerId>99</dre:CustomerId>
           <dre:Name>Test Testsson</dre:Name>
           <dre:Zip>11351</dre:Zip>
        </dre:DeliveryAddress>
        <dre:DeliveryNote>
           <dre:File></dre:File>
           <dre:Name></dre:Name>
        </dre:DeliveryNote>
        <dre:DeliveryRows>
           <dre:DeliveryRow>
              <dre:ArticleNumber>1</dre:ArticleNumber>
              <dre:ProductName>Kalsong</dre:ProductName>
              <dre:Quantity>0</dre:Quantity>
           </dre:DeliveryRow>
           <dre:DeliveryRow>
              <dre:ArticleNumber>2</dre:ArticleNumber>
              <dre:ProductName>Trosa</dre:ProductName>
              <dre:Quantity>1</dre:Quantity>
           </dre:DeliveryRow>
        </dre:DeliveryRows>           
        <dre:DeliveryServiceType>PICKUP</dre:DeliveryServiceType>
        <dre:Email></dre:Email>
        <dre:EmailCopy></dre:EmailCopy>
        <dre:ExternalId></dre:ExternalId>
        <dre:FutureDeliveryDate></dre:FutureDeliveryDate>
        <dre:GiftWrapping>1</dre:GiftWrapping>
        <dre:InvoiceAddress>
           <dre:Address1></dre:Address1>
           <dre:Address2></dre:Address2>
           <dre:City></dre:City>
           <dre:CountryCode></dre:CountryCode>
           <dre:Name></dre:Name>
           <dre:Zip></dre:Zip>
        </dre:InvoiceAddress>
        <dre:Language></dre:Language>
        <dre:OrderId>82712742424</dre:OrderId>
        <dre:OrderMark></dre:OrderMark>
        <dre:OrderType></dre:OrderType>
        <dre:OrderValue></dre:OrderValue>
        <dre:OriginalOrderId></dre:OriginalOrderId>
        <dre:OurReference>Test</dre:OurReference>
        <dre:PDF_DeliveryNoteURL></dre:PDF_DeliveryNoteURL>
        <dre:PDF_InvoiceURL></dre:PDF_InvoiceURL>
        <dre:PackingAlert></dre:PackingAlert>            
        <dre:PersonalMessage></dre:PersonalMessage>
        <dre:PickListComment></dre:PickListComment>            
        <dre:RestOrder></dre:RestOrder>          
        <dre:ReturnOrder></dre:ReturnOrder>            
        <dre:SMS_Notification>913131</dre:SMS_Notification>
        <dre:YourOrderId>81718191</dre:YourOrderId>
        <dre:YourReference>Test Testsson</dre:YourReference>
     </tem:Delivery>
  </tem:AddDelivery>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But I get error:

```
The  formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: 
There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
http://tempuri.org/:Delivery. 

The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the 
object of type DreamLogisticsService.Delivery. 
The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.'.
```

What is the problem? Is the values not converted to INT on the requesting server?

Please help!

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Your Delivery element has a number of sub-elements which are of types which cannot be passed an empty string as a value. Either remove the elements from your XML (they have a `minOccurs` property value of 0) or set them to an accepted value. E.g. `OrderType` is of type Int, `OrderValue` is of type Decimal, and both `RestOrder` and `ReturnOrder` are of type Boolean.

See your XSD here for type information: http://service.dreamlogistics.se/service.svc?xsd=xsd2